# Data not displayed in list

Tags: android

I am trying to set data into my `recyclerView` and I can't set the data into a list. When I debug, it's executing the statements and the values are found in logcat. But when I run, it is not found in the list. I have tried a lot. Can anyone please help. This is what I have done.

**Adapter1**

```
SelectedAdditionalItemsAdapter adapter = new SelectedAdditionalItemsAdapter(activity, row.getAdditionalItems(), row);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
         adapter.setData(row.getAdditionalItems());
```

**SelectedAdditionalItemsAdapter**

```
public class SelectedAdditionalItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectedAdditionalItemsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Product> rows = new ArrayList<>();

        Context context;
private OrderItem orderItem;


private Activity activity;

public OnOrderItemDeleteListner onOrderItemDeleteListner;



public SelectedAdditionalItemsAdapter(Context context,List<Product> rows,OrderItem orderItem) {
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
        this.rows=rows;
        this.orderItem=orderItem;
        }

public SelectedAdditionalItemsAdapter(){

        }

public Product getItem(int position) {
        try {
        return rows.get(position);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
        }
        }

public void setData(List<Product> rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
        }


@Override
public SelectedAdditionalItemsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {


        return new SelectedAdditionalItemsAdapter.ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.additional_item_cell, parent, false));
        }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SelectedAdditionalItemsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Product row = getItem(position);

        holder.bindVehicle(row, position);

        }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        try {
        return rows.size();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return 0;
        }
        }

private void removeItem(int position) {
        try {
        this.rows.remove(position);
        }catch (Exception e) {

        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    TextView title, remarkView, quantityView, priceView;
    ImageView deleteButton;
    CircularNetworkImageView imageView;
    private Product row;

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_view);
        remarkView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.remark_view);
        imageView = (CircularNetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        quantityView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity_view);
        priceView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price_view);
        deleteButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);

    }
        public void bindVehicle(final Product row, final int position) {

        deleteButton.setTag(position);///added


        this.row = row;
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                         orderItem.removeProduct(row);
                    removeItem(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();



            }

        });

        try {
            this.title.setText(row.getName());
            if(row.getDescription() != null && row.getDescription().length() > 0) {
                remarkView.setText(row.getDescription());
                remarkView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                remarkView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            String title = row.getName();
            imageView.setImageUrl(null, RequestQueue.getImageLoader());
            ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
            int color = generator.getColor(title);

            try {
                if(title.length() > 0) {
                    TextDrawable drawable2 = TextDrawable.builder()
                            .buildRound(title.substring(0, 1), color);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable2);
                }
            }catch (NullPointerException e) {
          }
quantityView.setText(Integer.toString((int)row.getQuantity()));
            priceView.setText(row.getPriceForUnitToDisplay());    
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}}

public interface OnOrderItemDeleteListner {
    void onDeleteItem();
}}
```

`This is my xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <driver.codepoints.com.driver.utils.CircularNetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
            <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/title_view"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/delete_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tint="@color/android_red"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/remark_view"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/quantity_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/accent_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                     />
                <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
                    android:id="@+id/price_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/login_text_hint_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                     />    
            </LinearLayout>    
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: share relevant portions of `activity and adapter code`

Comment: what does `adapter.setData`  exactly do ?

Comment: I have called SelectedAdditionalItemsAdaper in Adapter. and I called Adapter into an activity. What should I post. Kindly help@NavneetKrishna

Comment: share code for `SelectedAdditionalItemsAdapter .java` , also what is the list (may be an arraylist) that you are trying to pass into your adapter

Comment: I have posted@NavneetKrishna

Comment: Would you please try to use `context` instead if `parent.getContext()` for inflating layout.

Comment: Ya, problem at parent.getContext(). Because ViewGroup parent is not initiated first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `context` instead if `parent.getContext()` for inflating layout.

Change this

```
 return new SelectedAdditionalItemsAdapter.ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.additional_item_cell, parent, false));
```

to

```
 return new SelectedAdditionalItemsAdapter.ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.additional_item_cell, parent, false));
```

Also set layoutManager to `RecyclerView`.

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thankyou for helping. I tried it but its not working@Faysal Ahmed

Comment: Thankyou .....Thanks a lot.. I got that....but there is one problem. I am able to set only one value@Faysal Ahmed

Comment: Can you please help in that also

Comment: Happy to help you. please check how much data you get from `row.getAdditionalItems()` this.

Comment: I am getting as 2. But the list displays only 1@Faysal Ahmed

Comment: remove this `adapter.setData(row.getAdditionalItems());` first.

Comment: I think the problem is recyclerview height related issue. Please check the height of recyclerView in XML. Hope you find the issue.

Comment: <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="100dp">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </FrameLayout>